# "System.NotImplementedException" thrown when trying to set source of navigation window. WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have been troubleshooting this problem for quite some time. Whenever I call the following method:

```
 public void View(string newView) 
    {
        try
        {
           view = new Uri(newView, UriKind.Relative);
           //NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
           //nav.Navigate(view);
           this.Source = view;    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(),"Error");           
        }
    }
```

The compiler outputs A first chance exception of type **'System.NotImplementedException'** occurred in System.dll

The application does not crash!

Any Assistance would be very much appreciated!

---

***Other Relevant Code Snippets***

The Method is called by a button click event in a separate XAML's C# file called HubView.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        View = @"/Acounting;component/Pages/UserAdd.xaml";
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.View(View);
    }
```

HubView.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="Acounting.Pages.HubView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="299" d:DesignWidth="497"
Title="HubView">


<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Row1 -->
    <Button Content="User Form" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0 ,0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <!-- Row2 -->
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>

    <!-- Row3 -->
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96.2" Height="41" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="Container.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Source="Pages/HubView.xaml" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" ShowsNavigationUI="False">
```

UserAdd.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class UserAdd : Page
{
    public UserAdd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

UserAdd.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="Acounting.UserAdd"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="299" d:DesignWidth="497"
Title="UserAdd">

<Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: And `UserAdd.xaml` code? Your problem is probably there, either in a Converter or in some class you're binding to

Comment: I think you have a method which has no implementation. Try doing a `Ctrl+F` search for `NotImplementedException`. That will be the line that's throwing the error.

Comment: Mmmh... Pretty clueless then. Haven't worked much with `NavigationWindow` myself, so can't be much more helpful. Other than what Mike is suggesting, if I were you I'd just try and remove or comment any properties you're setting in XAML, to see if any of them is causing the problem.

Comment: @fergul I copied your code but I am not able to reproduce your issue. If you use the [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591151(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of setting the this.Source property do you still get the exception?

Comment: @MisterXero No, but I get a null reference exception! What framework where you targeting?

Comment: @fergul I am targeting 4.5.1

Comment: @fergul Could you post your stack trace for the exception? Might have some clues in there.